# VBA - Vlookup multiple rows from another sheet, paste as values

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to figure this out, but had to luck.

I have a list that starts on A5 on worksheet**2**. I need to Vlookup each item from A5 down until the last cell in column A (list will never be the same size). The data/info will be on worksheet**1**. Then paste (as values) the data starting in cell C5 and until the last corresponding cell in column A.

The data on worksheet**1** will most likely always been in columns A:L, but this could change so i'm hoping to make it dynamic where the code can know which column the data ends. Data will always start on A1.

I'm not sure how to loop this. Looking to achieve this through VBA using a macro-enabled button I started programming.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
sub lookup
  dim x as long, lastrow as long

  lastrow = Sheet2.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row

  for x = 5 to lastrow
    Sheet2.Range("C" & x) = worksheetfunction.xlookup arg1:=sheet2.range("A" & x), _
    arg2:= Sheet1.Range("A:A"), arg3:=Sheet1.range("B:B")
  next x

end sub
```

I think you are going to need to solidify which column you are wanting to return in order to make the VBA simple. Depending on the column I think you can loop through until you find the header you are looking for, but it would be better if it was always in the same place.

This code says, for the sheet length of sheet2, starting in c5 xlookup your key, find it on sheet 1, and return the column that has your data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a row number in Worksheet1 and then intend to transfer all available data from that row. That would be a job for the *MATCH* worksheet function or `Find` in VBA. Please try the code below.

```
Sub MatchAndCopy()
    ' 213

    Dim Rng         As Range                ' source data
    Dim Arr         As Variant              ' one row of data
    Dim Crit        As Variant              ' match criterium
    Dim Fnd         As Range                ' match found
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    Dim Spike       As String               ' collecting failures
    
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      ' speed up execution
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For R = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Crit = .Cells(R, "A").Value
            Set Fnd = Rng.Columns(1).Find(Crit, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Fnd Is Nothing Then
                If Len(Spike) Then Spike = Spike & vbCr
                Spike = Spike & String(5, " ") & """" & Crit & """ in row " & R
            Else
                Arr = Fnd.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, Rng.Columns.Count - 1).Value
                .Cells(R, 2).Resize(1, UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Len(Spike) Then
        Spike = "Transfer of the following items failed." & vbCr & Spike
    Else
        Spike = "Data were transferred successfully and without errors."
    End If
    MsgBox Spike, vbInformation, "Transfer report"
End Sub
```